# search for text within string in laravel or mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I use `my SQL` as backend for my project, and I need to get all record from `database` where some part of inputted string is available in `database` string like:

`table = seller`

```
id  company_name  seller_name
1   companyname1  seller1
2   companyname2  seller2
3   companyname3  seller3
4   companyname4  seller4
```

Given string is `1105 companyname1 is outstanding`

So i need to get `id = 1` for a given string if it is possible with `laravel` or `MySQL` then please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a query using `like`:

```
where $YourString like concat('%', companyname, '%')
```

Note:  There are situations where one company name might be sufficiently like another ("company1" and "company10").  If this is an issue, regular expressions might help.

Comment: could you please explain it more i got syntax error.

Comment: @HirenMangukiya . . . `like` is a basic operator in SQL and I have no idea what syntax error you got.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to convert that string to an array.

```
    $str = "1105 companyname1 is outstanding";
    $str = explode(' ' , $str);
    $results = Seller::whereIn('company_name' , $str)->get();
```

---

### Note:

As you are converting random strings to an array, there will be a mistake where the user input some more spaces.

Let say the user input a string like `$str = "1105   companyname1 is outstanding";` this will create some more elements. Like

```
array(
  0 => '1104',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'companyname1',
  3 => 'is',
  4 => 'outstanding'
)
```

So, to avoid that, I have to recommend you to split out some more spaces. You can do by

`$str = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: Thanks for it some time company name contain `" "` (space) that time it won't work.

Comment: You should use LIKE insted